# setting a select tag on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<%= form_tag("/posts/create") do %>
  <div class="form">
    <div class="form-body">
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <div class="form-error">
          <%= message %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="continent">
        <label>continent<br>
          <%= @post.continent %>
          <%= select :continent,
            [["Africa","AF"],["North America","NA"],["Oceania","OC"],["Asia","AS"],["Europe","EU"],["South America","SA"]],
            :prompt => "Select" %>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="country">
        <label>country<br>
          <%= @post.country %>
          <%= select :country,
            [["Japan","JP"],["China","CH"]],
            :prompt => "Select" %>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="title">
        <label>title<br>
        <textarea name="title"><%= @post.title %></textarea>
        </label>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="POST">
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want to set a select tag for choosing user's continent and country in the form
But It doesn't work well

I've tried some way to solve this problem. 
And I just got the shape which is like **"Select tag"** but it's only included **"prompt"** 
Please give me some advice.

Comment: You can use the select tag like this.
select_tag "destination", raw('<option value = "AF">Africa</option><option value = "NA">North America</option><option value="OC">Oceania</option>'), :prompt => "Select"

Answer (score 0):

[FormOptionsHelper](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)`s select takes these args

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

Try explicit putting options like this:

```
select :post, :country, [["Japan","JP"],["China","CH"]], { :prompt => "Select" }, { other_html_options }
```

If you are in a form context make this

```
<%= form_tag("/posts/create") do |form| %>
  <%= form.select :country, [["Japan","JP"],["China","CH"]], { :prompt => "Select" }, { other_html_options } %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

First start off by creating the correct routes:

```
resources :posts
```

In Rails you create a resource by sending a POST request to the collection path ('/posts').

Then create the form with `form_for(@post)` or `form_with(model: @post)` (Rails 5.1+) and bind the model instance to the form builder.

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <div class="form">
    <div class="form-body">
      <% f.object.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <div class="form-error">
          <%= message %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <div class="continent">
        <%= f.label :continent do %>
          <%= f.select :continent,
            [["Africa","AF"],["North America","NA"],["Oceania","OC"],["Asia","AS"],["Europe","EU"],["South America","SA"]],
            prompt: "Select" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="country">
        <%= f.label :country do %>
          <%= f.select :country,
            [["Japan","JP"],["China","CH"]],
            :prompt => "Select" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        <%= f.label :title do %>
        <%= f.text_area_field :title %>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This lets you reuse the same form for updating the resource. Also when you use the input helpers rails will properly name the inputs so that you can whitelist them with:

```
params.require(:post).permit(:continent, :country, :title)
```